# How to include a variable into the name of a Ruby Motion screen?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I could not find out how I can include a variable number into the name of a screen (Ruby Motion)

```
@id = "2"

  def button
    open Home{@id}Screen.new(nav_bar: false)
  end
```

In a URL there is a # before and it works,

```
https://thisistheurl/#{id}.json"
```

but it does not work in the method above. The hash is being interpreted as commenting out.

Many thanks for helping!

Comment: What is the result you want? `Home2Screen.new...`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're calling a "screen" is a constant. The `#{...}` syntax works inside string literals, which is what the URL in your URL example is. So one way to solve this is to answer the question, "How do I get a constant from a string?" The answer is [`const_get`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Module.html#method-i-const_get):

```
def button
  name = "Home#{@id}Screen" # => "Home2Screen"
  screen = self.class.const_get(name)  # => Home2Screen
  open screen.new(nav_bar: false)
end
```

This is a kind of metaprogramming and is common in Ruby. However, this is one case where there are better ways to accomplish what you want. Another way to solve this is to answer the question, "How can I create a mapping of numbers to constants?" The answer is a Hash:

```
SCREEN_NUMBER_MAP = {
  1 => Home1Screen,
  2 => Home2Screen,
  # ...
}

def button
  screen = SCREEN_NUMBER_MAP[@id] # => Home2Screen
  open screen.new(nav_bar: false)
end
```

This option is better because it's more declarative and less "magic."

Comment: please see my post above explaining more precisely and showing the crash report.

Comment: I've edited my answer to fix the NoMethodError. `const_get` needs to be called on a module, ergo. `self.class.const_get`. However, it sounds like you have bigger problems. If you have a different constant (Home34Screen, Apple34Screen, Banana34Screen, ...) for every variation of your screen, you need to rethink your design, because you're going to keep running into problems like this. Figure out how to separate the parts that stay the same between screens from the parts that are different, so you have just one screen (or just a few) that can handle variations.

Comment: No, the problem is not solved yet as it seems that Ruby Motion does not accept const_get.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the modified script which works fine! And thanks for your advice, I'll work on a solution.  Thanks again, Daniel

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your note, Jordan!

Your proposal #1 (`const_get`)  crashed (details below), 
proposal #2 is not practical for my purpose.

Sorry if I had been not clear regarding what result I want to achieve and regarding 'what is a screen'.
My question had not been 'How do I get a constant from a string?' but How do I insert a constant (e.g. `id = '34'`) into a Screen name (e.g. `'Home#Screen') => Home34Screen`?

Situation: In my script for a certain screen (eg. 'recipe 34) there are different buttons calling to open different screens, e.g. `Home34Screen`, `Apple34Screen`, `Banana34Screen` etc.

I want to be able to copy the script recipe 34 so it can be used in recipe 58 as well. 
Now, instead of inserting the constant 58 into each of the buttons I just want to change the id from '34' into '58'.

This explains why your proposal #2 would not be a practical solution.

Your proposal #1 is fine but it resulted in a crash.

My new syntax is:

```
def button_swipeleft
  name = "Tonprobe#{@id}Screen"
  screen = const_get(name)
  open screen.new(nav_bar: false)
end
```

Originally it had been:

```
def button_swipeleft
  open Tonprobe2Screen.new(nav_bar: false)
end
```

It might be significant to mention that I am using RubyMotion.
Crash report:

> 2018-02-14 06:22:15.725 plus123[16983:2203916] *** Terminating app due
>   to uncaught exception 'NoMethodError', reason:
>   'app/screens/ANDERE/9000-TONPROBEN/tonprobe1_screen.rb:69:in
>   `button_swipeleft': undefined method`const_get' for

Thanks a lot for advising!

(note regarding the rules: It seems that I am supposed to respond with a 'comment' or to edit my post if I want to clarify - I chose 'Post your Answer' as my comment is longer and needs formatting and editing my original post might lead to confusion.  This as my note as far as the rules in the forum are concerned.)

Comment: Editing your question will not cause confusion.